# BigQuery get row above empty column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, window-functions

Data:

```
SELECT 'aa' column_a, 'asdf' column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb', '' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ccc', 'asdf' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ddd', '' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'eee', 'asdf' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'fff', 'asdf'
```

[image]

What would be the best way to get the row right above the empty cell? For example, I'd like to filter out row 1 and 3 based on the fact that column_b in row 2 and 4 are empty (in this example). A simple where statement does not work unfortunately, but how would it be possible to get the row above an empty cell?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `lead()` - but you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows, I assumed `id`:

```
select t.* except(lead_column_b)
from (
    select t.*, lead(column_b) over(order by id) lead_column_b
    from mytable t
) t
where lead_column_b is not null
```

Note that this will filter out the last row in the table (because it has no "next" row). If you don't want that, we can add a little more logic:

```
select t.* except(lead_column_b, rn)
from (
    select t.*, 
        lead(column_b) over(order by id) lead_column_b,
        row_number() over(order by id desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where lead_column_b is not null or rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `lead()` function

```
with data as (
  SELECT 'aa' column_a, 'asdf' column_b UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb', '' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ccc', 'asdf' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ddd', '' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'eee', 'asdf' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'fff', 'asdf'
),
get_next_value as (
  select *, lead(column_b,1) over(order by column_a asc) as next_col_b from data
)
select column_a, column_b, next_col_b
from get_next_value
where ifnull(next_col_b,"Last Row") <> '' -- This accounts for the last row in the table
```